# Stoping a function untill I get an api response then resume with the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m really having problems with this. 
The function im using is checking a counter for every component of an array, to push an array to a variable only if the counter is less than the number y state.

The problem here is that when the counter reaches the limit y send the variable to an api, and in a succesfull response I restart the counter and empty the variable to do it all over again.

My problem is when i send the first one the api takes a time to give me a response but the rest of the array im cheking has already past and becouse I only reset the counter in the response, only one time the api is consulted

The code im currently using:

```js
cargaLotes() {
  let totallengthchange = this.Arraydata.length;

  this.cargaloader = true;
  this.Step = true;
  for (const values of this.Arraydata) {
    this.check(values);
  }

  // this.lenghtloader = this.Arraydata.length;
  let lengthafterPush;
  let lengthdivided;
  let lengthdisplay;
  const porcetaje = 1;
  const totaldisplay = 100;
  let lengtharray = this.Arraydata.length;
  const lengtharraystatico = this.Arraydata.length;
  const temp: any = this.Arraydata;
  if (this.Step === true) {
    let contador1 = 0;
    (contador1 < 500) {
      temp.forEach(data => {
        if (contador1 < 499) {
          this.arraytosend.push(data);
          contador1 = contador1 + 1;
          if (contador1 === lengtharray) {
            this.service.(service)(this.arraytosend).subscribe(resp => {
              this.notificacion.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Se Cargaron los Productos', 'warning');
              this.getProductoPrice();
              this.lenghtloader = 100;
            }, err => {
              this.notificacion.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Ocurrio un error', 'danger');
            });

          }
          if (contador1 === 499) {
            this.arraytosend.push(data);
            this.service.(service)(this.arraytosend).subscribe(resp => {
              console.log(resp);
              totallengthchange = totallengthchange - 500;
              lengthafterPush = totallengthchange;
              console.log(lengthafterPush);
              lengthdivided = lengthafterPush / lengtharraystatico;
              lengthdisplay = porcetaje - lengthdivided;
              this.lenghtloader = lengthdisplay * totaldisplay;

            }, err => {
              console.log(err);
              this.notificacion.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Ocurrio un error', 'danger');
            });
            lengtharray = lengtharray - 500;
            this.arraytosend = [];
            contador1 = 0;
          }


        }

      });
    }
  } else {
    this.ArraydataDuplicates = [];
    for (const values of this.Arraydata) {
      this.showDuplicates(values);
    }
    this._snackBar.open(`El Archivo Contiene Productos que ya han sido registrados!.`, 'Ocultar', {
      duration: 5000
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Checkout Promises. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Can you please provide a demo in stackblitz, preferably with minimal code. Observables are extremely powerful, so you can do pretty much anything you want with them. We just need to understand what you want to achieve first.

Comment: Just few points to help you write question so anyone can understand the Question immediatly, It increases chances to answers right away:


1. Phrase question such that anyone else can use the same question if they have the same problem.
2. Put code in smal sections and explain what each section does and what it should do

Comment: In this question you mention API request. Show that code clearly and seprately and maybe add comments to tell how are you makiing the API request

Comment: In this question you mention counter and resting of that counter. Make it clear where that code is and where you rest is and where you think it should pause

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms, your code is buffering values into an array, which then gets sent to an API. This will repeat until there are no values remaining in the array. You are sending batches of values to an API.

I will give a very simplistic example of the kind of pattern you could use below. I have ignored a lot of the side-effects that your code is performing - these should be simple enough to integrate once you have the main pattern sorted.

component.ts

```js
private batchSize = 500;
private data: number[];

// handle some event that determines when the batches should be sent
onSend() {
  // assume this.data has been set somewhere

  this.sendBatches().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('done');
  });
}

private sendBatches(): Observable<any> {
  // splice the data to get the batch of data to be sent
  const batch: number[] = this.data.splice(0, this.batchSize);
  if (batch.length === 0) {
    return of(null);
  }    

  return this.sendData(batch).pipe(
    // recursive chain the observable calls
    switchMap(() => this.sendBatches(batchSize))
  );
}

private sendData(data: number[]): Observable<any> {
  // mock call to the API
  return of({}).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-60605895